# WPF Designer error: frameworkName cannot be an empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Recently for no apparent reason my VS2012 designer has been failing to open up and xaml file in the project. All of them were working okay before. I didn't change project settings or install vs updates (using update 4).

The error I get is:
System.ArgumentException:
The parameter 'frameworkName' cannot be an empty string.

I've looked at similar issues and tried to delete my temp folder as well as switching target framework versions but to no avail!

Any suggestions? Tearing my hair out over this one.

Update: I've noticed that as I remove references to other projects in my solution the designer then loads. I need those references so this isn't a solution but maybe it hints at the cause

Comment: you better Clean your Solution . Delete the Obj/Debug Folder in which project you are getting error. Remove References .. Add Reference Again and then Check

Comment: I've isolated it to a reference in one of the other projects. Not quite sure why but I'll post an answer when I do.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Did you get your issue fixed? Any chance you remember the fix?

Comment: @phonetagger not yet. I ended up editing purely in xaml for a while. As my question states I know there is a problem with a refernced assembly. I will work on thisvagain soon and update this if I find an answer.

Comment: @phonetagger using VS2013 solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLR projects are using a cpp file in the temp directory, e.g. `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cpp` (depends on the used framework version). Usally this file looks like:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
[assembly: System::Runtime::Versioning::TargetFrameworkAttribute(L".NETFramework,Version=v4.6", FrameworkDisplayName=L".NET Framework 4.6")];
```

But sometimes it gets corrupted and the strings are empty. Just open it and copy the strings from the corresponding cs-file.

I added a pre-build-step to my projects, so I get an error, if the strings are empty:

```
findstr /C:".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" "%temp%\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cpp" > nul
```